# Problema con foreach() | Resultados Duplicados - PHP

Tags: php

Venía por aquí para saber si me pueden ayudar con este problema, sé que en realidad no es un problema pero no se como hacer para que muestre lo que le pido, dejo code:

Aquí tengo los foreach (el $link lo incluyo con include)

```
<?php
foreach ($productos as $productos_vendiendo) {
foreach ($link->query("SELECT * FROM productos WHERE id = '$productos_vendiendo'") as         
$producto_obtenido_vender){ ?> 
<tr> 
<td> 
<div><?php echo $producto_obtenido_vender["nombre"]; ?></div> 
<div>
<?php echo substr($producto_obtenido_vender["descripcion"], 0, 20).'...';; ?></div> </td> 
<?php foreach ($cantidades as $cantidad_producto) { ?>
<td><?php echo $cantidad_producto;} ?></td> 
<td>$<?php echo 
$producto_obtenido_vender["precio"]; ?></td> 
<td>$<?php echo 
$cantidad_producto*$producto_obtenido_vender["precio"]; ?></td> </tr> 
<?php }} ?>
```

Esta es la url por la que paso los GET, despues de pasarlos los convierto a array con explode
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y este es el resultado:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
El problema es que me imprime el precio 2 veces, y es el mismo en el otro item, lo que quiero hacer es que en el primero aparezca 100 y en el segundo 200 (columna cantidad)
Y por cierto, aquí defino todas las variables necesarias:

```
$productos_get = $_GET["productos"];
$productos = explode(",", $productos_get);
$cantidades_get = $_GET["cantidades"];
$cantidades = explode(",", $cantidades_get);
$subtotal = 90;
```

Comment: no entiendo tu problema.. no estas mandando dos cosas?

Comment: si, pero quisiera que en el primer item saliera 100, y en el otro 200, no 100 y 200 en el mismo item

Comment: y donde esta eso explicado en tu pregunta?

Comment: Lo siento, olvidé explicar eso

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes cambiar tu foreach, por lo que logro notar solo estas llamando al primer item del array ($item['valor']

Con este foreach puede iterar por id y sus respectivos valore,
Ejemplo:

```
foreach ($array as $clave => $valor) {

echo "{$clave} => {$valor} ";
print_r($array);
}
```

En este caso solo seria a los foreach que 2 y 3

De igual manera puedes consultar la documentacion de PHP
https://www.php.net/manual/es/control-structures.foreach.php